# How to match filenames in different directories?(bash or python)

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have a set of files in two directories

~/Desktop/dir1 and ~/Desktop/dir2

I need to match files in dir1 to files in dir2 or vice versa

filenames in /dir1 are: 1.out, 2.out ... 21.out

filenames in /dir2 are: chr-1.out, chr-2.out ... chr-21.out

I wrote a plotting script in python which accepts command line arguments for filenames and builds some plots based on content of files. So the question is how to match files and provide it to a script? I tried to use bash, but I cant figure out how to do that. Maybe it is possible to that from python?

I could have done it by hands,  but I would rather learn how to do that automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bash, use parameter expansion:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for f in dir1/*.out
    echo "$f" "dir2/chr-${f#dir1/}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.
My script looks like this:
for f in ./dir1*.out; do
python ./plot.py "$f" "./dir2/chr-${f#./dir1/}" "$f"
done
The problem is that it is replacing files in dir2 with plots. Is there a way to provide just a number as a third parameter?

Comment: @YKY: `num=${f#dir1/}; num=${num%.out}`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively in Python (working from the desktop):

```
import os

for file1 in os.listdir('dir1'):
    for file2 in os.listdir('dir2'):
        if file1 in file2:
            print(file1)
```

There is probably a more efficient way of doing this but that's a quick and dirty method and should be relatively flexible.

Comment: Why loop over `list2` manually **and** use `in`? Isn't that rather redundant? I would think either a manual loop *or* `file1 in list2`.

Comment: because the file names aren't identical - which is annoying as hell. Assuming the names have these kinds of small variations, we'd have to settle for in. E.g. `'1.out' in 'chr-1.out' == True`. - Otherwise yes I would have just done the single loop with file1 in list2.

Comment: Another problem with this approach is that `'1.out' in 'chr-21.out' == True`.

Comment: True, that does rule out the naive `in` usage. Though as @chthonicdaemon points out this `in` usage is sub-optimal as well.

Comment: Optimally the filenames would actually match. If we wanted to make it more complicated we could check for duplicates and do a bit more work around that, or if the 'chr-' is 100% standard slice the file after the '-' and use `==` instead of `in`.